# Is there no fopencookie or fmemopen in MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, stream, mingw

What can I use instead to write custom streams?

Comment: You could use sprintf or asprintf

Comment: I think you mean `snprintf`. `sprintf` should never be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fmemopen` is POSIX but not part of the C standard. `fopencookie` is not part of any standard; it's a GNU function.

`tmpfile` makes a good portable replacement for `fmemopen`. These functions are nearly identical except that `tmpfile` tends to be slower and requires `fread` to get the data back out.

In general, if you might need your output to go somewhere other than a file, it's best not to write code that takes a `FILE *` but instead supports custom output callbacks or something.

Comment: Doesn't `tmpfile` create a physical file on hard drive? BTW. Are C++ streams not built over `FILE *`?

Comment: As far as plain C is concerned, `tmpfile` need not create a physical file, because there's no way a conforming program could observe whether it really does or not. For POSIX, the existence of the `fileno` function makes it possible to get at the underlying file descriptor, so one must exist. But the file is anonymous, and there's really no reason to care whether it's created except performance.

Comment: As for C++ streams, they are not built on stdio directly. I don't know C++ well, but my understanding is that both stdio-based and non-stdio-based streams exist, using the same base classes but different derived classes.

Comment: "For POSIX, the existence of the fileno function makes it possible to get at the underlying file descriptor, so one must exist."

From the man-page fmemopen(3) on Linux;

"There is no file descriptor associated with the file stream returned by these functions (i.e., fileno(3) will return an error if called on the returned stream)."

From my testing of fopencookie(3) it seems the same heuristic applies although it is not documented in the man-page; if you call fileno(3) on a file pointer returned by fopencookie(3) it returns -1 and errno says 9 "Bad file descriptor".

Comment: @abasterfield: In the case of `tmpfile` there really does need to be an associated file. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tmpfile.html. In particular "The tmpfile() function shall create a temporary file and open a corresponding stream" (here I don't see any way to read "file" except the POSIX meaning) and "The file is opened as in fopen() for update (w+)" (which implies a real file). `fileno` is only permitted to fail for stdio streams that do not have an underlying file.

Comment: The temporary file could be in an in-memory virtual file system, like `tmpfs` on Linux, and for performance purposes this is more like an in-memory buffer than a file on disk, although you still have to deal with system call overhead for write and read (unless the implementation has found a way to optimize that away - we could imagine an OS where temporary files are mapped into process memory more directly). Speaking of memory mapping, if `fileno` works on the temp-file and it is a real file, I think you could `mmap` it, and get direct+faster reads of what you've written.

Comment: Of course you might also never hit disk if you have a reasonable upper bound on how much you need to write into the temporary file: `setvbuf` on it with a buffer that big, in fully buffered mode. Unless the implementation flushes on seek or you write more than the buffer, you can then seek to the start of the file and read from the file handle without any disk overheads, even if there's a real file underneath, unused.

Comment: (Caveat re: `setvbuf` trick: you might be tempted to read from the buffer directly after the writes, rather than through the `FILE *`, but that's undefined behavior. I read that to mean that an implementation is free to for example put metadata in the buffer, or store the buffered data in compressed form (possibly only in some conditions, like when asked out-of-band to optimize for runspace over runtime), or whatever. And some optimizing compilers treat you hitting undefined behavior as you promising that your code actually won't hit that case, and delete/change code accordingly.)

Comment: Oh, and of course, even if a temporary file is created "on disk", it still might never actually hit disk, or might never delay your program for any actual disk-I/O. Modern kernels are pretty smart about that kind of thing - changes to disk tend to be cached/buffered in-memory at the OS level, only written out when there's enough memory pressure or when there's idle time or when explicitly asked to synchronize/flush, so a small temporary file "on disk" might never actually exist on disk, or the disk updates might only get written to disk asynchronously.